# Angular js single page application

Tags: angularjs

I am getting issues integrating my component developed in angular js to the existing application where it has header component and footer component which are developed in angular js.Its throwing  "Error: Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined" and referring controller name from existing components .I am planning to implement angularjs route for my component.Will that help or need to implement for whole application?.Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Have you defined your controller "MainCtrl" correctly and is the `js` file included?   Probably a good idea to post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Hi Ven, welcome to Stack Overflow. 

I'd suggest you read a bit more of the AngularJS documentation. As well, when asking a question here, its much more helpful if we can see what your code looks like.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  We would love to help you to sort out the error you are receiving, but unfortunately some code is required in order to diagnose these kind of messages.  You should consider updating your question with the appropriate code for review.  Please also see [mcve].

Comment: your edits haven't helped to clarify the question at all;  this is simply not answerable without code.